# Wrapping C++ code with function pointer as template parameter in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to wrap the following declaration written in C++ in cython:

```
template<typename T, double (*distance)(const DataPoint&, const DataPoint&)>
class VpTree
{...}
```

I've also got the following definition in C++:

```
inline double euclidean_distance(const DataPoint &t1, const DataPoint &t2) {...}
```

and I'm trying to wrap this in cython. This is what I've been able to come up with following the documentation:

```
cdef extern from "vptree.h":
    # declaration of DataPoint omitted here

    cdef inline double euclidean_distance(DataPoint&, DataPoint&)

    cdef cppclass VpTree[T, F]:  # F is almost certainly wrong
        ...
```

and build a wrapper around this:

```
cdef class VPTree:
    cdef VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance] tree

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.tree = VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance]()
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following errors:

```
------------------------------------------------------------

cdef class VPTree:
    cdef VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance] tree
                                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

unknown type in template argument

------------------------------------------------------------

cdef class VPTree:
    cdef VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance] tree

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.tree = VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance]()
                                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

unknown type in template argument
```

I suspect the problem lies in the `F` part of the definition, and I've tried various things in place of that e.g. `double(*)(DataPoint&, DataPoint&)` but this obviously results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Cython doesn't support non-type template parameters (that is what function pointer is) directly (I might have missed the memo though), but there is a well known *cname-hack* to achieve the goal.

Here, for a much simpler example:

```
%%cython --cplus            
cdef extern from *:
    """
    template<int val>
    int fun(){return val;}
    """
    int fun[T]()
```

i.e. an `int`-value as template parameter.

Now we have a dilemma: Cython expects T to be type and g++ (or other compilers) expects an integer value - here comes the *cname-hack* to our rescue:

```
%%cython --cplus            
...
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int val2 "2" 

def doit():
    return fun[val2]()
```

Cython believes `val2` to be a type (alias for `int`), but replaces it with `2` in the resulting c++ code (`fun<2>()`), thus c++-compiler sees an integer-value (`2` in this case), as it expects.

---

For your case that means adding:

```
%%cython --cplus            
...
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int euclidean_distance_t "euclidean_distance" 

cdef class VPTree:
     cdef VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance_t] tree

     def __cinit__(self):
         self.tree = VpTree[DataPoint, euclidean_distance_t]()
```

You actually don't have to wrap "euclidean_distance" at all, if you don't use it anywhere else in Cython code.

Comment: Wow, that's a neat trick. I hadn't come across that before. Thanks a bunch!